# Kendo UI Tabstrip Onclick event

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am trying to have a onclick event when a button in second tab is clicked and it has to go to third tab. I have seen it in jquery but couldnt implement in TS with angular 4/6

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
  <kendo-tabstrip id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip="tabstrip">
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tab 1'">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tab 2'" [selected]="true">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
       <button (click)="openApproachTab()" value="Approach"  class=" btn btn-accent m-btn m-btn--custom m-btn--icon m-btn--pill m-btn--air m-portlet__nav-link m-dropdown__toggle  ">
                            Start your budget</button>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tab 3'">
      <ng-template kendoTabContent>
        <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  </kendo-tabstrip>
`,
styles: [`
    kendo-tabstrip p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px;
    }
`]
})
export class AppComponent {

public openApproachTab()
{
   kendo-tabstrip.select(2);
}

  }
```

Wanted to see what type of code we need to write for onclick event openApproachTab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write jQuery imperative code to handle tab selection. You can simply use the `[selected]` property binding on each tab, and maintain the same on each tab click inside `selectedTab` variable. So basically on click of `openApproachTab` you can directly set `selectedTab` variable to `2`(3rd tab)

**Html**

```
<kendo-tabstrip (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tab 1'" [selected]="selectedTab == 0">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
      <p>Tab 1 Content</p>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tab 2'" [selected]="selectedTab == 1">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
      <p>Tab 2 Content</p>
    <button (click)="openApproachTab()" value="Approach"  class=" btn btn-accent m-btn m-btn--custom m-btn--icon m-btn--pill m-btn--air m-portlet__nav-link m-dropdown__toggle  ">
      Start your budget</button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Tab 3'" [selected]="selectedTab == 2">
    <ng-template kendoTabContent>
      <p>Tab 3 Content</p>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
</kendo-tabstrip>
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent {
    selectedTab = 1;
    public onTabSelect(e) {
      this.selectedTab = e.index
    }
    openApproachTab() {
      this.selectedTab = 2
    }
}
```

[**Demo Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caccte?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @AkarshKolanu glad to help you on it, Thanks :)